# How to pass InputStream datatype as a parameter for Quarkus Restful API resource service?

Tags: java, rest, post, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am developing a `REST` web service using `Java` and `Quarkus` framework. I would like to pass the `InputStream` as a datatype to my `Rest` Resource method as the method executed by the application accepts only `InputStream` as a input.

When I make the datatype as `String` and later convert it to `InputStream` then everything works out fine but only problem is that I need to convert the input from `String->InputStream` within the code every time.

I wanted to know if it's possible to accept the `InputStream` itself as a datatype for the Rest Resource API method so I can avoid the conversion from String to InputStream. When I do it I get the option only to read file in my Swagger-UI and method also not executed due to the InputStream data type.

Following is the current code I have which is working perfectly:

```
@Path("/api")
public class ConverterResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/converter")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> fileConverter(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") final String contentType, final String inputDocument) {
        final InputStream inputDocumentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputDocument.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        final TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        return contentType.equals("application/xml") ? testClass.xmlConverter(inputDocumentStream) : eventHashGenerator.jsonConverter(inputDocumentStream);
    }
}
```

I would like to achieve something like this so conversion can be avoided:

```
@Path("/api")
public class ConverterResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/converter")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> fileConverter(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") final String contentType, final InputStream inputDocumentStream) {
        //final InputStream inputDocumentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputDocument.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        final TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        return contentType.equals("application/xml") ? testClass.xmlConverter(inputDocumentStream) : eventHashGenerator.jsonConverter(inputDocumentStream);
    }
}
```

I quite new to Quarkus so not sure exactly if its possible or I am doing something wrong. Any help or suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add dependency for multipart support

   ```
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-multipart</artifactId>
   ```
2. Write your Resource like :

```
@Path("/api")
public class ConverterResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/converter")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> fileConverter(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") final String contentType, @MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput multipartInput) {
        final InputStream inputDocumentStream = multipartInput.getFormDataPart("file", InputStream.class, null);
        final TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        return contentType.equals("application/xml") ? testClass.xmlConverter(inputDocumentStream) : eventHashGenerator.jsonConverter(inputDocumentStream);
    }
}
```

Hope this help you